# Redux previous state already has new state value can't understand why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm new to the react redux environment and I currently facing a probleme that I have some difficulty to understand.

I made a page with list of link.
I can add a link to the list when I click on the button Add Link, then a modal appear with a form.

When I submit the form new link is add to firebase when I trigger my method addLinkItem from link.utils.js

I'm using react-thunk to dispatch when firebase add is success, an action how update my links state.

My problem is that at this moment my prevState already have my nextState value, so the problem is that my component Listlink is not refresh with this new state.

I hope I was clear enougth

- Firebase
- React, Redux, redux-logger, redux-thunk

You find all the project to this repo: https://github.com/FrancoisSilab/klaxoon-test-bookmarks/blob/master/README.md

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addLinkItem(inputValues);
  };
```

add-link-modal.component.jsx

```
export const addLinkItem = (link) => {
  return dispatch => {
    // On obtient la référence de la collection links
    const colRef = firestore.collection("links");
    // On ajoute le nouveau linkItem comme nouveau document
    colRef
      .add(link)
      .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
        link["id"] = docRef.id;
        dispatch(addLinkItemAction(link));
        dispatch(resetInput());
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
  };
};
```

links.utils.js

```
export const addLinkItemAction = (link) => ({
  type: LinksActionsTypes.ADD_LINK,
  payload: link
});
```

links.actions.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  linksItems: []
};

const linkReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LinksActionsTypes.GET_LINKS:
      return {
        ...state,
        linksItems: action.payload
      };
      case LinksActionsTypes.ADD_LINK:
        state.linksItems.push(action.payload);
        return {
        ...state,
        linksItems: state.linksItems
      };
      case LinksActionsTypes.DELETE_LINK:
      return {
        ...state,
        linksItems: deleteLinkItem(state.linksItems, action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default linkReducer;
```

links.reducer.jsx

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are mutating the state. Instead of pushing into the old array:

```
state.linksItems.push(action.payload);
return {
  ...state,
  linksItems: state.linksItems
};
```

...create a copy of the array and add to that one.

```
const newLinkItems = [...state.linkItems, action.payload];
return {
  ...state,
  linkItems: newLinkItems
}
```